# Use .fs functions in an .fsx script in F# (visual studio)

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, f#-data

I have written a bunch of function in an .fs file under a namespace and module and I would like to use them in an .fsx files for some testing with sample data. I tried loading into the fsi at the top of the fsx file "#load sample.fs" but I still am unable to use the functions.

How can I access the sample.fs functions in a seperate fsx file?

Thanks!

Comment: This should work - what error are you getting?

Comment: Activating my crystal ball, my guess is that the .fs file needs to be in a module

Comment: correct, had to open the namespace and the module in fsx.. thnx